# iOS:I have a requirement with textview become first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextview

When the `[sendTextField becomeFirstResponder]`, the `keyboard` will `upspring`, and `self.view` will upspring too.

I have a requirement , when `[sendTextField becomeFirstResponder]`, the `keyboard` upspring, but self.view do not upspring?

EDIT:For more clear for my question, I add a picture:

[image: the tableview do not upspring and the textview's back upspring with keyboard popup]

My requirement is:
The `tableview` do not upspring and the `textview's back` upspring with `keyboard` popup.

EDIT:For `Ajay Gabani`'s answer, I test in my `ipnone-5s` using `TPKeyboardAvoiding`'s example , and I found this, the tableView also `upspring` with the `keyboard`, the picture will show:

The origin status:

[image: The origin status]

The tableview upspring:

[image: The tableview upspring]

Comment: what have you done so far??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I am not able to comment on your question.

For your case "when [sendTextField becomeFirstResponder], the keyboard upspring, but self.view do not upspring?"

You can manage textfield within scrollview or tableview with keyboard appearance.

[TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Hope this might help you.

Comment: thank you to answer my question, you satisfy my requirement . By the way, what mean of "For your case "when [sendTextField becomeFirstResponder], the keyboard upspring, but self.view do not upspring?"" , my English is not good, what mean of your express?

Comment: No its not about english, I completely understand what is your requirement. I just want to clarify your requirement case that you want to Display keyboard without any other misbehaviour of application and UIView.

Comment: I am sorry this is not work for my requirement after test it in my project, and your example I test carefully and found at the bottom of`tableview`, it will upstring also.

Comment: It is also supporting tableview and collectionview with scrollview. If you want to use this case with table view use TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView and for collectionview use TPKeyboardAvoidingCollectionView. please search in sample project library.

Comment: I am sorry to test the `TPKeyboardAvoiding`, you can see my EDIT in question, the tableView upspring with keyboard, the Label 29 is the end of tableView, and this example is you provide to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use 3rd party SDK
you can use observer and manage UIView frame programatically like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
 {
     CGRect newFrame = [customView frame];
     newFrame.origin.y -= [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height; // Adjust your tableview position by taking keyboard height
     [tableView setFrame:newFrame];

 }completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {

 }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
 {
     CGRect newFrame = [customView frame];
     newFrame.origin.y += [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height; // // Adjust your tableview position
     [tableView setFrame:newFrame];

 }completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {

 }];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```